# Azure CLI az role definition update - microsoft.cdn/profiles/endpoints/Purge/action does not match any of the actions supported by the provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, rbac

I'm trying to update an existing role definition with the following command that is run in a DevOps pipeline

```
$roleDef = az role definition update --role-definition $r.FullName | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The $r variable holds the path to the custom role definition shown below:

```
{
    "Name": "DevOps Pipeline",
    "Description": "Used for deploying web application code, but not creating resources",
    "AssignableScopes": [
        "/subscriptions/sub-id-here"
    ],
    "Actions": [
        "Microsoft.Authorization/*/read",
        "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/*/read",
        "Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/*",
        "Microsoft.Insights/components/*",
        "Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/read",
        "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/*",
        "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
        "Microsoft.Support/*",
        "Microsoft.Web/certificates/*",
        "Microsoft.Web/listSitesAssignedToHostName/read",
        "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/join/action",
        "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/read",
        "Microsoft.Web/sites/*",
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/read",
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listkeys/action",
        "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/Purge/action",
        "Microsoft.Web/connections/write",
        "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/write"
    ],
    "NotActions": [],
    "DataActions": [
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/read",
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/write",
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/delete",
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/deleteBlobVersion/action",
        "Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/*/read",
        "Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/*/write",
        "Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/*/delete"
    ],
    "NotDataActions": []
}
```

My problem is, when this is run the following exception is thrown:

> ERROR: 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/Purge/action' does not match
> any of the actions supported by the providers.

Comment: I get a similar error stating "Status Message: 'Microsoft.Cdn/cdnwebapplicationfirewallmanagedrulesets/delete' does not match any of the actions supported by the providers. (Code:InvalidActionOrNotAction)" when I attempt re-run a pipeline and the same version of my code by pipeline. The pipeline successfully ran just a few days ago on Oct 13 and added that exact action. Checking the role definition in the portal, the JSON still shows the action.

Comment: I opened a support ticket with Microsoft and they indicated it was a problem with an updated API rollout. "This issue was due to a new API version not being rolled out in all of our production regions. The API is now in all regions." The problem is now resolved for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Stringfellow seems to be the same for me. The cause was due deployment change on the Azure side - nothing to do with my devops pipeline.